# LyX template for legislation?

Tags: lyx, templates, document-classes

Anyone know of any simple template for legislation which is easy to modify and looks great so I don't have to spend several hours to figure out the syntax?

Edit: By legislation, I mean something whose output resembles bills before the U.S. congress.

Comment: How do you define 'legislation'?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). And as UweZiegenhagen says, it would be helpful if you provided details as to exactly what you are looking for such as a sample document, or style.